# Combining 'while not' with try/except

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, try-catch

I get a page with `urllib2`, then parse it with `lxml`. There are generally two things that can go wrong: a `urllib2.URLError`, or a `httplib.IncompleteRead`

```
def get_page(url):
    response = None
    while not response:
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.URLError:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except httplib.IncompleteRead:
            print '**** IncompleteRead for response from %s, retrying' % url
        html_parser = etree.HTMLParser()
        tree = etree.parse(response, html_parser)
        return tree
```

There are a couple of obvious problems here:

1. The first `except` does the exact same thing as its preceding `try`.
2. The parsing with `lxml` will be attempted whether we have a `response` or not.

So:

1. What needs to go in the first `except`? Is `pass` acceptable?
2. My understanding is that only a single action should be attempted within a `try`, so I am loathe to move the parsing under there. Indeed a function itself should only perform a single action - does the parsing then belong in its own function?

Comment: If you want to retry in both cases, you can do `except (urllib2.URLError, httplib.IncompleteRead):` to handle both exceptions with the same code.

Comment: "There are a couple of obvious problems here" -- These problems aren't obvious to us since you haven't actually described what the code is supposed to _do_.  e.g. what is supposed to happen if `URLError` is raised?  What happens if `IncompleteRead` is raised?

Answer (score 3):

You can handle these cases with combinations of `continue` and `break` statements.  `continue` will jump back to the top of the while loop, `break` will jump out of the while loop.

```
def get_page(url):
    response = None
    while not response:
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.URLError:
            continue  # No response, try again
        except httplib.IncompleteRead:
            print '**** IncompleteRead for response from %s, retrying' % url
            break  # Bad response, don't try again?
        html_parser = etree.HTMLParser()
        tree = etree.parse(response, html_parser)
        return tree
```

---

There are other flow control tools you could mix in here as well (like the `else` clause for `try` which gets executed only if an exeception *doesn't* happen in the block):

```
try:
    pass
except Exception as err:
    print("Don't see this.")
else:
    print("You will see this.")
```

as opposed to:

```
try:
    raise Exception
except Exception as err:
    print("You will see this.")
else:
    print("Don't see this.")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to move the parsing out of the `while` loop, rather than into the `try` block. That way, you can keep looping trying to get a valid response, and only attempt to parse if the request was successful.

```
def get_page(url):
    response = None
    while not response:
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.URLError:
            print '**** URLError for response from %s, retrying' % url
        except httplib.IncompleteRead:
            print '**** IncompleteRead for response from %s, retrying' % url

    html_parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(response, html_parser)
    return tree
```

I've also updated the `except` block for the `URLError` to work essentially the same as the `IncompeleteRead` block. I'm not actually sure if that's appropriate, since some `URLError`s might not be fixed by retrying (e.g. if the server doesn't exist, that probably won't change while you're retrying). If it should be a fatal error (fatal to this function, at least), you probably want to `raise` in that `except` block, rather than letting the loop continue. Here's a version that treats `URLErrors` more seriously than `IncompleteRead`s:

```
def get_page(url):
    response = None
    while not response:
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.URLError:
            print '**** URLError for response from %s, giving up' % url
            raise
        except httplib.IncompleteRead:
            print '**** IncompleteRead for response from %s, retrying' % url

    html_parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(response, html_parser)
    return tree
```

The `raise` keyword by itself (with no expression after it) re-raises the current exception. You could also raise a different error if that would make more sense in your application (e.g. a `ValueError`, to indicate that the provided URL was no good).